# What is the datatype used in the DS18B20 called?

Tags: types, floating-point

In the temperature chip DS18B20 the temperature value is stored with 12bit, where the integer part is 2 complement and the lower 4 bits is the decimal part.

The layout is like this:

```
  Bit 11     Signed
  Bit 10..4  2^7  .. 2^0
  Bit  3..0  2^-1 .. 2^-3
```

More info [DS18B20.pdf page 4](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS18B20.pdf)

So to represent the number 0.5 we set bit 3 since 2^-1 is 0.5. 
And to represent the number 0.75 we ser bit 3 and 2 since 2^-1 + 2^-2 = 0.75.

What is this type of representation called in mathematical and computer science terminology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like fixed point notation:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic

Perhaps a better link:
http://chortle.ccsu.edu/AssemblyTutorial/Chapter-29/ass29_7.html

Comment: With a scaling factor 2^4? Since if I start with 0.5 that is represented like 0x8 (0b1000) if we divide with 2^4 (8/2^4) we get 0.5.

Comment: Would that then be called "a 12 bit fixed point with scaling 2^4"?

Comment: Yea, the scaling factor is essentially how much you need to scale by to accommodate the radix point at its location. Since you need to shift the radix point left by 4, 2^4 is the correct amount to divide the base value by to obtain the fixed point value. The scaling factor would probably be 1/(2^4), since you're dividing the original number. Since four of the sign bits are redundant I would agree that 12 bit fixed point sounds correct.